# Using bash extended globs file masks in variables in find and loop

Tags: bash, glob

I am trying to match files using a pre-set file mask in a variable.

```
mat $ ls -lQ /tmp/Mat
total 0
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Mat Mat 0 Mar  3 14:32 "testfile1"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Mat Mat 0 Mar  3 14:33 "testfile1.gz"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Mat Mat 0 Mar  3 14:33 "testfile2"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Mat Mat 0 Mar  3 14:33 "testfile2.gz"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Mat Mat 0 Mar  3 14:38 "testfile2.gz#id=142"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Mat Mat 0 Mar  3 14:34 "testfile2test"
-rw-rw-r-- 1 Mat Mat 0 Mar  3 14:34 "testfile2test.gz"
mat $ file_mask=*file2*
mat $ ls /tmp/Mat/$file_mask?(.gz)
testfile2.gz  testfile2test.gz
```

I am trying to get: `testfile2 testfile2.gz testfile2test testfile2.gz`

Comment: `?(.gz)` huh? tell us your intention...

Comment: That's an extended glob. It means optionally match a `.gz` suffix.

Comment: Are you getting a 'no match' error from `failglob` here?

Comment: I have the file mask *file2 in a variable and I want to add ?(.gz) to match testfile2 and testfile2.gz

This works if I run:
     `ls *file2?(.gz)`

but not if I run
     `filemask=*file2;
     ls $filemask?(.gz)`

Comment: Note that on the _command line_ `extglob` is by default OFF. Once turned on, `filemask=*file2; ls $filemask?(.gz)` works for me in both bash 3.2.57 and 4.3.30. If `failglob` is in effect in your _script_, you should see an _error_ when nothing matches (`no match: ...`); when you say "doesn't match anything", do you mean you see this error (as @EtanReisner has already asked)?

Comment: I see this error, for example:
`no match: /tmp/Mat/*file2*?(.gz)` yet if I run `ls /tmp/Mat/*file2*?(.gz)` it returns the result I expect (testfile2 and testfile2.gz)

Comment: Just found out that my script is in bash, but my shell is in ksh. Changing to bash causes the error:
`/tmp/Mat/*file2*?(.gz) : No such file or directory`. Any idea why this is failing? And is there a way to get it to work without switching my script to ksh?

Comment: What does `ls -lQ /tmp/Mat` output (add it to the question))?

Comment: I'll rewrite the question a bit :P

Comment: interestingly using *(.gz) seems to almost achieve what I want... why doesn't ?(.gz) work? I thought ? meant zero or one occurrence.

Comment: What is your bash version? 3.2.57 seems to have a _bug_ with `extglob` on where `*file2*?(.gz)` matches `testfile2.gz` but not `testfile2`, for instance; if you drop the 2nd `*`, it finds both (doesn't happen in 4.3.30); however, with your set of test files, I do _not_ get _no_ matches at all. (If you want me to be notified of follow-up comments, include @mklement0)

Comment: @mklement0 I am running bash version 3.2.25, so I presume this is just down to that bug :( I'll have to use the *(.gz) workaround.

Comment: @Mat: Got it. Since others may bump into this bug, I've summarized the findings in an answer, which also offers an alternative to the more permissive `*(.gz)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the outcome:

**tl;dr**

- The **OP experienced unexpected behavior** due to  a **bug in 3.x versions of bash** relating to certain extended glob patterns, i.e., **with `shopt -s extglob` in effect**.
- However, **even without the bug, the code doesn't work as intended**, because the **globbing pattern `*file2*?(.gz)` is effectively the same as `*file*`** - which would match files with *any* suffix, not just `.gz`.
- To only match names containing `file2` that *either* have *no* suffix at all, *or*, if they have [at least] one, with a [last] suffix of `.gz`, use **`*([^.])file2*([^.])?(*.gz)`** (this works fine in bash 3.x too). Note that, as with the OP's patterns, this **requires extended globbing** to be activated with `shopt -s extglob`.

---

The assumption is that the OP's **intent** is as follows:

Match only names containing `file2` [before the 1st suffix, if any] that *either* have *no* suffix at all, *or*, if they have [at least] one, with a [last] suffix of `.gz`

E.g., match files `file2` `file2-a`, `some-file2`, `file2.gz`, `file2-a.gz`, `file2.tar.gz`, but not `file2.no` (because it has a [last] suffix that is not '.gz').

While there *is* a bash 3.x bug that affects patterns such as `*?(...)` - see below - **there's no good reason to use `*?(...)`, because it is effectively the same as just `*`**, given that `*` matches *any* sequence of characters, *including suffixes*.
The solution below is *not* affected by the bug.

You **cannot use `*` for matching only the *root* of a filename (the part before the [first] suffix)**, because `*` matches *any* string, whether part of a suffix or not.

Thus, extended glob `*([^.])` must be used, which matches a string of any length containing any character *except `.`* (a period).

Also, to account for the fact that a filename may have *multiple* suffixes, the optional `.gz`-matching part of the pattern should be `?(*.gz)`.

To put it together:

Note: `shopt -s extglob` must be in effect for the commands to work.

```
# Create test files; note the addition of "testfile2.tar.gz", which SHOULD 
# match, and "testfile2.no", which should NOT match:
$ touch "testfile1" "testfile1.gz" "testfile2" "testfile2.gz" "testfile2.gz#id=142" "testfile2test" "testfile2test.gz" "testfile2.tar.gz" "testfile2.no"

$ ls -1 *([^.])file2*([^.])?(*.gz)
testfile2
testfile2.gz
testfile2.tar.gz
testfile2test
testfile2test.gz

# The same, using a variable:
$ file_mask=*([^.])file2*([^.]) # NO globbing here (no globbing in *assignments*).
$ file_mask+=?(*.gz) # Extend the pattern; still no globbing.
$ ls -1 $file_mask   # Globbing happens here, due to unquoted use of the variable.
# Same output as before.

# Using a loop should work equally:
for f in *([^.])file2*([^.])?(*.gz); do echo "$f"; done
# Same output as before.

# Loop with a variable:
$ file_mask=*([^.])file2*([^.])
$ file_mask+=?(*.gz)
$ for f in $file_mask; do echo "$f"; done    
# Same output as before.
```

---

**Obscure extended-globbing bug in bash 3.x**:

Note that the bug is unrelated to whether or not variables are used.

I don't know in what version the bug was fixed, but it's **not present in 4.3.30**, for instance.

In short, **`*?(...)` mistakenly acts as if `*+(...)`** had been specified.

In other words: independent simple pattern `*` followed by extended pattern `?(...)` (match *zero or 1* `...` instance) effectively behaves like `*` followed by `+(...)` (match *1 or more* `...` instances).

**Demonstration**, observed in bash 3.2.57 (the current version on OSX 10.10.2; the OP uses 3.2.25):

```
$ touch f f.gz # create test files

$ ls -1 f?(.gz)    # OK: finds files with basename root 'f', optionally suffixed with '.gz'
f
f.gz

# Now extend the glob with `*` after the basename root.
# This, in fact, is logically equivalent to `f*` and should
# match *all files starting with 'f'*.
$ ls -1 f*?(.gz)    
f.gz
# ^ BUG: only matches the suffixed file.
```

Comment: Thank you for making that clear. I can see how your more robust workaround would work well - how would I use this in a for loop? `for file in $glob; do #something; done`

Comment: @Mat: I've substantially rewritten the answer and I think I found the proper solution. In short: you need to use a different extended pattern for logical reasons, and, luckily, that also bypasses the bug.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0 that's extremely helpful and your solution seems really robust. Ideally if I could I'd update bash, but this works fine till then :)

Comment: @Mat: My pleasure; glad it worked. Re bash: I hear you.